# Easiest way to run/debug ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I just upgraded my ASP.NET (Framework) MVC app to ASP.NET Core 2.2. That process was painful enough, however even more painful is running the web app locally.

**Issues with running in IIS Express:**

- If I launch the app with F5 (to enable debugging), then once I stop debugging the browser window closes so I have to start over on the homepage each time after changing any code.
- If I launch the app with Ctrl + F5 (no debugging), after a few rebuilds the website seems to die, meaning that any new page requests just say host not found. I then have to Ctrl + F5 again to get it going again, but then I'm back on the homepage.
- Visual Studio 2019 sometimes decides to launch the webpage in my existing Chrome window on a new tab, but sometimes decides to launch it in an entirely new Chrome window. After several minutes of dev, I'm left with multiple tabs and windows open.

**Issues with running in IIS:**

- The only way it runs is if I manually edit my Web.config to have the proper values for processPath (`"dotnet"`) and arguments (`"./bin/Debug/Housters.Web.dll"`). Visual Studio likes to inject in aspNetCore `processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"` every time I build or run my app, despite me having `IsTransformWebConfigDisabled = true` in my `.csproj`. So I constantly have to go into *git* and revert these changes, or else my app will fall back to the dreaded ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure page.
- Assuming the Web.config has the proper values, after running the application in the browser I can no longer build the project. Instead it gives the error: Error  MSB3027 Could not copy `"obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Housters.Web.dll"` to `"bin\Debug\Housters.Web.dll"`. Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "IIS Worker Process (15496)". IIS is using the ASP.NET Core web app's dll so I can't actually update my code and build it, that's just great. The workaround is to recycle my IIS app pool, but this gets old REAL quick when you need to do it before every single rebuild.
- Attaching to the w3wp.exe process isn't causing any breakpoints to be hit, so I can't debug under IIS (IIS Express debugging works fine.)
- The launch profiles that I configured in launchSettings.json are ignored. For example, when I choose my IIS launch profile (which has "http://localhost" as the launchUrl and applicationUrl), if I F5 or Ctrl + F5 it opens "http://localhost:62551/" in the browser window.

So this begs the question, how are others developing/running/debugging their ASP.NET Core apps on their local dev machines? Maybe most web developers have moved away from ASP.NET to purely javascript frameworks like Angular, React, and Vue so I'm just out of luck? Or am I missing something that will make ASP.NET Core development less painful?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem OP? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @fdrobidoux Microsoft is trying to improve IIS support for ASP.NET Core, but it's still much worse of an experience than in .NET Framework. This is a good issue to follow: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/546858/bin-files-locked-by-iis-worker-process-1.html?childToView=662667

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the experience with ASP .NET Core has greatly improved compared to the past.

However, certain glitches still remain. For what regards IIS Express (in production we use Kestrel), you can try these things with Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 (they work for us):

> If I launch the app with F5 (to enable debugging), then once I stop debugging the browser window closes so I have to start over on the homepage each time after changing any code.

Just don't use the page: let the tab/page open, spawn another tab/page and use the latter for debugging. This way your session is going to be as similar to a production environment. We have Firefox as default browser, but we usually debug with Chrome, therefore, not touching the process spawned by Visual Studio keeps IIS Express alive.

> If I launch the app with Ctrl + F5 (no debugging), after a few rebuilds the website seems to die, meaning that any new page requests just say host not found. I then have to Ctrl + F5 again to get it going again, but then I'm back on the homepage.

It seems that cleaning the whole solution **twice** solves the issue (at least for us). The first time you clean the solution, IIS Express still serves the site. Apparently, this should be the designed way (cannot find the documentation about that).

If that does not work, it might happen that a Visual Studio service is stuck. In this case, shut down Visual Studio (I know, it's painful), wait a little bit, and kill all the `dotnet.exe` currently running after verifying they are part of Visual Studio.

> Visual Studio 2019 sometimes decides to launch the webpage in my existing Chrome window on a new tab, but sometimes decides to launch it in an entirely new Chrome window. After several minutes of dev, I'm left with multiple tabs and windows open.

This is partially what I said previously. Although painful and resource expensive, having multiple windows open allows us to survive.

For reference, we use the very same configuration on debug and release (with kestrel).